# vba code to copy cells from previous row if a cell has a specific name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula in Excel that will check the value of a cell and if it is True then it will copy the data from the previous cell, if it is not, cell will remain blank.

```
=IF(A2="Summary",B1,"")
```

I would want to create VBA code that would check the range of A, A1:A500 and if it is equal to Summary  then copy the data in the previous row from columns B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L.

So some columns already have existing data in them .

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyDataFromPreviosRow()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A2:A500")
        If c.Value = c.Offset(-1).Value Then
            c.EntireRow.Columns("B:L").Value = c.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Columns("B:L").Value
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So what if to trigger this event I need to find the word Summary as it goes through the range in column A.  sorry I am really bad at coding and just starting to read up on it

Comment: `c` represents the current cell that is being iterated over in `"A2:A500"`.  `If c.Value = "Summary" then`

Comment: You should start by watching this series [Into to VBA](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on youtube